# Is it more common to use table_id or id in database design

Tags: database, database-design

I have a situation where I would like to know if it is more commonplace to use table_id or just id? (in my opinion, using table_ would cause slight confusion as to if it a foreign key). Which do people prefer, and is there really any difference between the two? Or should it just be left up to picking one and being consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main currents in terms of naming columns in tables:

##### Schema Namespace

This strategy is the traditional strategy that was conceived by teams documenting the "data dictionary" of a database in the 70s. The idea is that the name itself of the column tells you which table it belongs to across the whole schema or database. For example, `CLIENT_NAME` would represent the name of the client in the `CLIENT` table.

There are variations of this strategy where a limited number of letters are assigned as prefixes (specially for M:N relationship tables) because at the time column names were limited to 6 or 8 characters in many databases. For example, the date of purchase of a car by a client could take the form `CLI_CAR_DATE`, `CLICAR_DATE`, or even `CLCADT`.

Examples:

- A primary key "id" column of the entity table "car" would be named `CAR_ID`.
- A foreign key on a child table "document" that *points* to "car" would take the same form: `CAR_ID`. This allows the use of natural joins; however, it should be pointed out that there are compelling reasons to avoid natural joins at all cost, that are not discussed here.
- Foreign keys on a table "transfer" that has multiple (two) relationships (seller and buyer) with "person" pollutes this strategy. They could be named: `PERSON_BUYER_ID` and `PERSON_SELLER_ID` because both cannot have the same name `PERSON_ID`; it doesn't allow natural joins anymore (good).

##### Table Namespace

In this strategy (that is newer) column names do not include the name of the entity they belong to, but only their *property* name. This strategy aligns more with object design, and produces shorter names (i.e. less typing). The name of the table must be indicated when mentioning a column. For example, you would need to say the column `NAME` on the table `CLIENT`.

Examples:

- A primary key "id" column of the entity table "car" would be named `ID`.
- A foreign key on a child table "document" that *points* to "car" would take the form: `CAR_ID`; this is the same solution as the previous strategy.
- Foreign keys on a table "transfer" that has multiple (two) relationships (seller and buyer) with "person" could be named: `BUYER_ID` and `SELLER_ID`. They could follow the longer names as the previous strategy, but the goal here is typically to have shorter names so the app source code gets easier to write and to debug.

##### Summary

I personally like the second one, but there are teams who adhere to both strategies and there's no clear winner. My leaning towards the second one is [I think] the first one suffers from longer names (more typing), longer SQL (more errors), cryptic names (they don't play well with ORMs and app objects), and foreign keys that cannot follow the strategy well. In fact, virtually all the primary keys in my databases are named `ID` regardless of the specific entities.

But on the flip side, some teams value very highly the idea of knowing the table name of a column by just looking at it. And this is great for big databases (with 200-1000 relational *fact* tables) that can become quite complex, specially for new members of a team.

But above all, pick one and be consistent.